# Can I blur the Eevee shadows?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I checked on the Soft Shadows, but it looks as if there are multiple overlapping shadows. I know the Eevee shadows cannot be accurate, and that is fine, but can I at least blur or smooth the shadows so that it would look like 1 shadow instead of multiple shadows?

Cycles [image: Cycles]

Eevee [image]

Eevee soft shadodws [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soft shadows are obtained by means of sampling. To eliminate the banding, set *Render > Sampling* to a higher value